# expect().to.be.a(Error) not working on throw error _ chai

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

this is my function I am trying to create a test for it:

```
function foo(obj) {
  
    if(typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null &&Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == '[object Object]'){
    
  // do something
  
    }else{
        throw new Error(`function test() only accepts [object Object],  you passed: ${Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)}`, )
    }
  };
```

and this is my test case:

```
it("it should complain with typeof", ()=>{

    try{
        foo(["aaaa"])
    }
    catch (error){

        chai.expect(error).to.be.a(Error)
    }
})
```

but I am not able to pass the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```js
expect(error).to.be.an('error')
```

Also `'Error'` or `.a('error')` will pass the test too.

Tested with this code (defined in the [docs](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/)):

```js
expect(new Error).to.be.an('error');
```

Also you can use `to.throw()` to expect an error thrown.

Answer (score 1):

To check exception it's better to use:

```
expect(function () {}).to.throw();
```

So in you code:

```
it("it should complain with typeof", ()=>{
  expect(()=> foo(["aaaa"]) ).to.throw();
})
```

By the way, to check Error explicitly:

```
it("it should complain with typeof", ()=>{
  expect(foo(["aaaa"]).to.be.an('error')
})
```

[Chai docs](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/)